# How to get the size of a docked control while the form is minimized?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I noticed that when a control is docked (or anchored), and the form is minimized, the `Control.Size` property returns an empty size (i.e., `{Width=0, Height=0}`). Here's some code to reproduce:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
        groupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        groupBox1.Text = "Some Title";
        this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss - "));
                Console.WriteLine(groupBox1.Size.ToString());
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This will print the size of the GroupBox as long as the form is not minimized. Once the form is minimized, it starts printing zeros.

**Is there a way to get the actual size of a docked/anchored control even if the form is minimized?**

I'm looking for something similar to [`Form.RestoreBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.restorebounds) but for child controls, not the form itself. The controls will be docked in another child container.

Comment: Have you checked:  `groupBox1.FindForm().PreferredSize`? Multiple docked Containers inside the same Form will change that value. A Control docked on one side, will return the measure of the side that is not docked. Maybe you could specify why you need a measure when the Form is minimized and/or what you plan to do with it.

Comment: Btw, if you want to run a Task instead of using a Timer, you should BeginInvoke() those `Console.WriteLine()` calls: you're accessing Controls from a Threadpool thread (sure, it's a test and you're just reading...). You should also move that code to the Load event.

Comment: @Jimi `FindForm().PreferredSize` returns very small size; I'm not sure exactly what it represents. Also, I'm not sure how the `PreferredSize` property _of the form_ helps with the size of a child control. Yes, you're right, I agree that using a timer or `BeginInvoke` is more appropriate but this was just a quick and dirty test to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Jimi As to why I wanted to do this, I'm trying to save the `SplitterDistance` value of several `SplitContainer` controls (as a percentage of the control's size) before the form closes. For now, I decided to save the values as soon as they're changed instead of waiting for the form to be closed...

Comment: ..The other problem is that when trying to restore the values, I need to get the new size of the control (which is incorrect if the form is minimized). Well, I can wait for the form to be activated but I noticed that the `Size` value also doesn't get updated if the control is on another tab (I thought getting the size while the form is minimized might work for this as well but looks like this should be a different question). Do you think I should post a new question regarding different tabs?

Comment: I think that, if you need to store those values, you have to handle `OnResize`, or both `OnResizeBegin` and `OnResizeEnd`, while of course checking `this.WindowState`, if you don't need/want to store values when the Form size `!= FormWindowState.Normal`. These methods (or the event thy rise) is often combined with `OnSizeChanged` to determine if the Form can be dragged, to avoid maximizing it when it's dragged near the edge of the Screen and any time you need to register a size change for any other reason.

Comment: The `Form.PreferredSize` is determined/modified by Controls docked in its ClientArea, so the size of the docked Controls is the difference between the size of the Form in Normal state and the Size of the Controls docked on one side. E.g., if you have just one Control Docked to Fill, PreferredSize is equal to the NormalSize + Borders. With one Control docked to, say, `Right` with `Width = 100`, Form.PreferredSize is now `(Form.Width - DockedControl.Width, Form.Height)`. So, if you add a Control and dock it to Fill, the Size of this Control is `Form.PreferredSize - BorderSize` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be something like:

```
private class GroupBox2 : GroupBox {

    Size restoreSize = Size.Empty;

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        // could also confirm the parent form is non-null and its WindowState is minimized
        Size s = this.Size;
        if (s.Width > 0 && s.Height > 0)
            restoreSize = s;
    }

    public Size RestoreSize {
        get {
            return restoreSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't require creating custom controls. Will accept this if no one comes up with a better answer.